# @Resource not injecting environment entry

Tags: java, xml, environment-variables, java-ee-6, code-injection

I recently saw a post that explained in JAVA EE, instead of using a `.properites` file, a better way to specify Configuration Properties is in a `web.xml` file and then injecting them inside the Class where the properties are needed.

This is my `Web.xml`

```
 <env-entry> 
   <env-entry-name>pacakageName.ClassName/number</env-entry-name> 
   <env-entry-type>java.lang.Integer</env-entry-type> 
   <env-entry-value>123</env-entry-value> 
 </env-entry>

 <env-entry> 
   <env-entry-name>country</env-entry-name> 
   <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type> 
   <env-entry-value>Spain</env-entry-value> 
 </env-entry>
```

And in my Java class, when I use the JNDI way I am able to get the value

```
InitialContext initialContext = new javax.naming.InitialContext();  
String countryName = (String) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/country");
```

This works, but when I try to use the new way of using `@Resources` and injecting the value, the value is not read from the `web.xml`

```
  @Path("loginService")
  public class LoginService{
    @Resource() int number;
     //constructor and other methods
   }
```

I am using Tomcat 7...Could anyone help me out what I am doing wrong.

I referred this doc:
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/env_entry/env_entry.html

Comment: Show the code for the class you're using the `@Resource` in.

Comment: How is your 'pacakageName.ClassName' annotated? Probably it is being instantiated in a wrong way.

Comment: @italo I haven't annotated the class,should I?

Comment: @Kayaman I posted the class where I am using Resource...I am injecting it in the field and using it somewhere inside a method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class is not the kind that supports the `@Resource` annotation. It needs to be a Java EE component, like an EJB for example.

This is because the container is the one that injects the resources, and it only considers components as valid injection targets. Also for this reason the resource must be defined before the container starts, so you can't inject resources that you put into JNDI during runtime.

Comment: @Kayaman..Thanks for the answer,but can't we do it in a servlet?,it is managed by tomcat

Comment: @user3897395 Well, your class doesn't seem to be a servlet. It doesn't extend `HttpServlet`.

Comment: I know,I just asked it as a question,i will try it on a servlet.

Comment: @user3897395 Did it work on a servlet? By all logic it should.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have `beans.xml` file in WEB-INF folder (this enables CDI) and then change your variable to `java.lang.Integer` like this:

```
@Resource(name="pacakageName.ClassName/number") 
Integer number;

@Resource(name="country") 
String country;
```

It works fine in Java EE 6 container that supports CDI for example [WebSphere Liberty profile](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/introducing_the_liberty_profile/)